# Why do we use parameters in linear regression for multiple variables problems?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to machine learning and I am confused with the use of parameters in linear regression for multiple variables. I do understand the hypothesis function's parameters (I know that theta 0 is the y-intercept and theta 1 is the slope) but I can not understand the use of them in the multiple variables cases (I thought that they might represent other dimensions but is it their slopes, intercept, etc?)

Please help because I am a 15-year-old beginner and I am really interested in learning machine learning but my math is not still all that complete and I still don't understand some core concepts in ML.

Thank you so much for your contribution!

Comment: How familiar are you with concepts of linear algebra?

Comment: https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319110790 currently half off

Comment: If you have multiple predictor variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$, then the linear regression model is $\hat y(x, \theta) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 + \ldots \theta_m x_m$. Here, $\theta_k$ is the slope in direction $x_k$.